# Excel IF Formulae , working with Number ranges

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a formulae I am trying to work on but it seems not to be working. I am working with number ranges

3.5 - 4   None

3.4- 3   Low

2.9  - 2  Medium

1.9 - 0  High

I have IF formulae which is suppose to give me a result based on the ranges. I cant seem to make it work

```
=IF(D13>3.5,"None",IF(D13<3.4,"Low",IF(D13<2.9,"Med",IF(D13<1.9,"High"))))
```

Comment: What inputs does this fail for?

Comment: If I put 1 it says Low, instead of high. For 3.5 it says False.

Comment: The way that you are using inequalities which point in different directions does,'t make sense

Comment: @JohnColeman I had them in the same directions but kept getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your inequalities point in a consistent direction:

```
=IF(D13>3.5,"None",IF(D13>3,"Low",IF(D13>2,"Med","High")))
```

You can tweak `>` vs. `>=` to control what happens at the boundary points.